# I don't want any splashscreen for ios - cordova

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I am using Sencha Touch and have my own animated splash screen there. I don't want to have default Corodva splash screen. I am using all latest version of sencha-cmd, corodva etc.

I tried a lot of things, 
- removing splash images from /Resources folder in xcode project.
- changing cordova/config.xml to remove any splashscreen preferences
- changing app.js file to remove any startup images reference.

but strangely I am not able to get rid of cordova splash screen (though I can replace it with any image i want), what could be the issue?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Cordova there is a flag to disable the autoshow of the splashscreen.

You might want to install the splashscreen plugin for cordova.

But:
The loading screen of Sencha Touch has to be inside the index.html and not inside Sencha, because that would need Sencha to be completly loaded.

The demo splash screen from Sencha is also inside the index.html. You can find the css in the top part and the divs for the loading screen at the bottom.

all platforms:

```
<!-- Define splashscreen name -->
<preference name="splashscreen" value="screen" />
```

Android:

```
<!-- Do not auto hide splash on Android -->
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/>
```

iOS:

```
<!-- Do not auto hide splash on iOS -->
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
```

Comment: will you be more specific on that Cordova flag please. I have searched a lot already.

Comment: updated my post with specific information for the config.xml file

Comment: As far as I understand, we can't remove iOS splashscreen, as Apple Store needs it

Comment: That is not part of the question. Please open a discussion in a forum, where you can discuss how useful it is to remove the splashscreen overall. This tag will only outhide the splashscreen on iOS not solve your personal taste on having it at all.